# ffmpeg how can I get the overlay to apply to all images in the slideshow

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay, slideshow

This command applies the overlay image to only the first image of the slideshow series. I messed with labeling and can't figure out the correct labels to get the overlay to apply to all images in the video.

```
/opt/bin/ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/3 -start_number 1 -i %01d.jpg -i $watermark.png -filter_complex "pad=500:500:(500-iw*min(500/iw\,500/ih))/2:(500-ih*min(500/iw\,500/ih))/2:color=white,overlay=250:420" out.mp4 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this works:

```
/opt/bin/ffmpeg -y -framerate 1/3 -start_number 1 -i %01d.jpg \
                -loop 1 -framerate 1/3 -i $watermark.png \
                -filter_complex "pad=500:500:(500-iw*min(500/iw\,500/ih))/2:(500-ih*min(500/iw\,500/ih))/2:color=white,overlay=250:420:shortest=1" \
                out.mp4 2>&1
```

If you want to show the same overlay image on all frames, you need to loop the overlay image. Since the looping will go forever, you need to stop with `-shortest` option to stop encoding when the first input ends.

Comment: Thank you @kesh. Those changes created a 100x bigger output file and it says it is corrupt when I try to play it.

Comment: My bad, `shortest` should be `overlay` option not output option. fixed in the post